# Create bash script to upload backup over FTP

Tags: backup, bash, ftp

im working on my own bash file to backup DB and transfer over ftp.
problem is the output is:

**Could not open file for writing.**

my code is:

```
DATE=`date +"%FT%T"`
DB_NAME="clcl"
DB_USER="clcl"
DB_PASSWORD="evfdfd"
LOCAL_BACKUP_DIR="/backup"
FILE_NAME="$DB_NAME-$DATE.sql.gz"
mysqldump -u $DB_USER  -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME | gzip  > $LOCAL_BACKUP_DIR/$FILE_NAME

ftp -n << EndFTP
open REMOTIP
user USER PASS
binary
hash
cd /
lcd /backup
put $FILE_NAME
bye
EndFTP
```

Comment: How are you running this script? Do you have write permission in that directory?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that you will have write permission in the root directory! Choose the correct directory.

Comment: change / to /mysql still get error: Could not open file for writing.
all folders have 777 perm in FTP

Comment: I found Solution: code is fine. problem is because of file name contain : symbol so change Date to new value: 
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S`